# I have a problem with token expiration, which goes with image url

Tags: google-photos

Can we refresh image tokens, with access token we get from authentication ?

In our case we get photos with pagination, and show those photos as mosaic. When we get all photos, after few hours, those photos we got, return Forbidden (403),